# Reading arguments in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Very simple question, but I have very little knowledge of shell script. What does the following command mean, when reading the arguments that were passed to the script?

```
TXT=${1,,}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converts a variable to lower case.

Example:

```
$ var="Hello World"
$ echo ${var,,}
hello world
```

In your case, `$1` refers to the first argument passed to your shell script, so `TXT=${1,,}` converts the first argument to lower case and stores it in another variable called `TXT`.

Type `man bash` and you will find the following detailed explanation of this expression:

> ${parameter,,pattern}
>
> Case modification.  This expansion modifies the case of alphabetic char-
>          acters  in parameter.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just
>          as in pathname expansion.  The ^  operator  converts  lowercase  letters
>          matching  pattern  to uppercase; the , operator converts matching upper-
>          case letters to lowercase.   The  ^^  and  ,,  expansions  convert  each
>          matched  character  in  the expanded value; the ^ and , expansions match
>          and convert only the first character in the expanded value.  If  pattern
>          is  omitted,  it is treated like a ?, which matches every character.  If
>          parameter is @ or *, the case modification operation is applied to  each
>          positional  parameter  in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>          If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the case mod-
>          ification  operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and
>          the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: This feature was also introduced in version 4.0, so if you are using an earlier version (such as what ships with Mac OS X), you'll get a bad substitution error instead.